Is resin printing suitable for enclosures?
For some customers I need to print enclosures for electronic projects. PLA is ok, they don't require harder materials like ABS or ASA. The most critical part is the first layer since it is the one actually exposed and must be perfect from an aesthetically point of view.
I've upgraded to a Creality K1 Max but I'm still having issues for the first layer (see this question).
A friend of mine suggested to try a resin printer.
I did a search on the Internet but it seems they are most used for small models with fine details and shiny finish.
I wonder if it would be suitable to print enclosures, something like these ones:

I'm not asking an opinion about your personal taste... but if the choice of a resin printer is correct to print such an object in terms of strength, feasibility and finish.

It can be found that it is strongly advised not to print flat surfaces flat on the build plate of a resin printer, so you need to be aware that you need to print these boxes slanted with support tree structures. Is that a downside for you?

@0scar it's not a problem if the final result is good!

The choice of a resin printer is correct to print these type of enclosures in terms of strength, feasibility and finish. Bare in mind though that the suctioncup effect can affect the outcome and you might need to add a hole somewhere or orient the enclosure differently. Resins can be strong/tough enough, but the hassle of rinsing and curing can make it a bit more time consuming.
The Creality K1 Max, however, is also very capable of printing a multiple of these enclosures at a time, with ease.

Thanks. I also think my K1 Max should do the job, but I'm still struggling with the first layer finish. Currenty, the results are not acceptable.

I learned that the Z-offset has a big impact of the "squish" of the first layer and can make the difference between a horrible and beautiful first layer. Also leveling the bed with as many as possible points (5x5 grid) helps to get an even first layer. Printing upside-up and with "ironing" can make the top look somewhat acceptable. It will cost you some supports and a horrible interior finish though.
